# Get all DynamoDB rows with DynamoDBMapper query api

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am making DynamoDBMapper query api call and its returning PaginatedQueryList. In my code, i am directly converting this PaginatedQueryList to java list which makes my code lose some of rows as dynamoDB have not loaded all rows in PaginatedQueryList.

How can i force DynamoDB query call to make sure that all table rows are loaded in PaginatedQueryList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the issue.  When you loop through the values in the PaginatedQueryList it will automatically fetch data that it doesn't have.  If you need all of this data in a List, loop through the PaginatedQueryList data and copy it to your list.  The API will do the correct thing for you.

Virtually all of the Amazon libraries handle large amounts of data by pagination.  Some return data a bit at a time and you have to go back to get more.  This is part of designing for a potentially huge amount of data - not returning 100,000,000 rows at once and trying to stuff those all in memory.